# Creating credential object from IDP Metadata with OpenSAML v3

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, opensaml

I am trying to validate the SAML response I get back from SSO Sircle (IDP). In order to do that, I am using the IDP metadata provided by SSO circle (https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml) in order to create the credential object with the IDP public key as follows:

```
    FilesystemMetadataResolver idpMetadataResolver = new  FilesystemMetadataResolver(new File("C:\\idp_metadata.xml"));
    idpMetadataResolver.setRequireValidMetadata(true);
    idpMetadataResolver.setParserPool(new BasicParserPool());
    idpMetadataResolver.initialize();

    MetadataCredentialResolver credentialResolver = new MetadataCredentialResolver();

    credentialResolver.setRoleDescriptorResolver(new BasicRoleDescriptorResolver(idpMetadataResolver));

    CriteriaSet criteriaSet = new CriteriaSet();
    criteriaSet.add(new EntityIdCriterion("https://idp.ssocircle.com"));
    criteriaSet.add(new EntityRoleCriterion(IDPSSODescriptor.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME));

    X509Credential credential = (X509Credential)credentialResolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);
```

However, this throws an exception when trying to initialize the idpMetadataResolver:

```
net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.ComponentInitializationException: Component identifier can not be null
at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.AbstractIdentifiedInitializableComponent.doInitialize(AbstractIdentifiedInitializableComponent.java:65)
at org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.AbstractMetadataResolver.doInitialize(AbstractMetadataResolver.java:188)
at net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.component.AbstractInitializableComponent.initialize(AbstractInitializableComponent.java:61)
```

I am very new to OpenSAML and I've been mainly looking at examples and tutorials online but most of them are written for OpenSAML v2.0. I was wondering if I am doing something wrong when initializing the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging on the OpenSAML 3 Java docs and the Shibboleth dev community, I think I found an answer to my question. The Metadata resolver object needs to be setup as follows:

```
    FilesystemMetadataResolver idpMetadataResolver = new FilesystemMetadataResolver(new File("C:\\idp.xml"));
    idpMetadataResolver.setRequireValidMetadata(true);
    idpMetadataResolver.setParserPool(XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getParserPool());
    idpMetadataResolver.setId("someidentifier");
    idpMetadataResolver.initialize();
```